# Lots of unnecessary and repititious output in clisp when I paste in new functions

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I just started using clisp again (after about 20 years). Now, I get the following text after it displays EACH line when I paste in a new function:

```
You are in the top-level Read-Eval-Print loop.
Help (abbreviated :h) = this list.
Use the usual editing capabilities.
```

Generally, the function still works. This happens even when I start with a fresh copy of clisp. How can I get clisp to stop this seemingly unnecessary output? I thought that it should take in the entire function and then let me know if it found errors. It does this even when there are no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The code you paste probably contains `Tab` characters](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-rl-tab).

PS. [You now owe me 10 zorkmids](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-fine).

Comment: Right you are!!!  Do you accept potrzebies ... I don't have any zorkmids.

Comment: As the FAQ says, the definition of a zorkmid is up to you, the payer. :-)

Comment: google (which is evil) image search will yield you a zorkmid. I have gotten away with paying such to sds, and he has been most gracious.

Comment: This unfortunately is not a correct answer to the issue.